# Nuget.exe cannot get through proxy when running by Jenkins

Tags: proxy, jenkins, nuget

I am using Jenkins to update NuGet packages but the problem is it does not work with Jenkins. I checked log file and copied the command running it manually and it works.

I invalidated the proxy on Nuget.exe.config and it still works (when getting manually.) So, I think proxy on the config file may not used or it's something wrong with my configuration. (Nuget.exe ignores configuration file if it's invalid.)

Here is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="http_proxy" value="url:port" />
        <add key="http_proxy.user" value="a" />
        <add key="http_proxy.password" value="b" />
    </config>
    <solution>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
    </solution>
</configuration>
```

Proxy server does not need user and password so it doesn't matter. Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be the issue?

```
Default Location

The default location for NuGet's configuration file is %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config (DOS) or $ENV:APPDATA\NuGet\NuGet.Config (PowerShell). 
APPDATA's value is OS, system drive, and current user dependent. For example: D:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.config.
```

From:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-file

Or you make sure you're calling your specific file:

```
The default configuration file can be changed through -ConfigFile option. For example, "-ConfigFile c:\my.config" means using file c:\my.config instead of %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config as the default configuraion file.
```

Which "identity" (domain\loginname) are you using?

The other idea:

Set the variables via the command line:

```
nuget config -Set HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1 -Set HTTP_PROXY.USER=domain\user
```

from

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference

Comment: Use -ConfigFile option at the end. Exaple: nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.password=password -ConfigFile C:\nuget.config

Answer (score 0):

Note that Jenkins is run as a service, so by default it is run by user **NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM**.

If you open %APPDATA% it will lead you to the AppData of current user, so any changes to %AppData%/Roaming/NuGet/Nuget.config won't have any effect on Jenkins.

What you need to do is to go to the AppData of NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM and modify/add Nuget.config which is here:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\
```

Comment: Mine was located at `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`